# Click an image of an image gallery and get the source

Tags: jquery

I have an image-gallery like following

```
<div class="row gallery necklace">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery1" class="FirstImage" src="./images/gallery/jewellery1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery2" src="./images/gallery/jewellery2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery3" src="./images/gallery/jewellery3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

If an image is clicked I need to get its src (may be use alert() to show the src); how is this possible using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('img').on('click', function() {});` targets the `img`elements in the DOM and adds event function of click to them. you can get the attribute source using `.attr('src')` and `$(this)` targets the specific img that you clicked on to trigger the event function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
     src = $(this).attr('src');
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row gallery necklace">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery1" class="FirstImage" src="./images/gallery/jewellery1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery2" src="./images/gallery/jewellery2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery3" src="./images/gallery/jewellery3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind `click()` event handler, to get image source inside callback function use `this.src`, this refers to the clicked dom object

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        alert(this.src);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row gallery necklace">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery1" class="FirstImage" src="./images/gallery/jewellery1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery2" src="./images/gallery/jewellery2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-box">
        <img id="jewellery3" src="./images/gallery/jewellery3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```